# Hash url not converted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am trying to make my route redirect but i don't know why "#" converted into "%23"

is there any way on how this url hash not converted ? help me.
here is my code

```
 return RedirectToAction("Update", "List", new { id = Model.ListId + "#Information" });
```

%23Information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uri.EscapeUriString or HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode is the correct way to escape a string meant to be part of a URL.

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("url") 

Uri.EscapeUriString("url")
```

More information :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

[Update]

Or in your case you can simply write below code :-

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("Update", "List", new { id = Model.ListId })+ "#Information");
```

Comment: where and when that code to be place, do i have to make a function to that? thanks

Comment: you can write the code when you are creating url for your operation! in your case before redirecting

Comment: can you give me an example sir on how to use that utility, i'm beginner in routing sir, do i have to replace the other code in this case  "new { id = Model.ListId + Uri.EscapeUriString("#Information") }"?

Comment: thanks sir: i change my code and it works return       Redirect(Url.Action("Update", "List", new { id = Model.ListId  })+ "#Information");

Comment: okk @A.J I have updated my answer according to ur comment so that it can be helpful for other people!